# How to remove header while appending the data to csv using dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have a requirement where I am reading data from the database and writing it to a file but the file should have only one header. I am using batch processing here as I need to read huge volume of data and appending the data to the same file. However, for each transaction header is added, how can I write header only once while writing records multiple times?

I know we can achieve this using for-each, but I want to know if this is possible using batch processing.

Current Output:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
abc  333  5ad  gag
col1  col2  col3  col4
ddd  455  d44  ggg
```

Expected Output:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
abc  333  5ad  gag
ddd  455  d44  ggg
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is because you are always writing CSV with the headers. You need to set `header=false` in the CSV Writer options. Besides that, I recommend also aggregating rows before writing hence it will be more performant and you can even try setting `deferred=true` to improve times.
This is a sample code for you to have an idea of how to proceed. The only "ugly" part is writing the headers at the beginning.

```
    <flow name="AppendFileInBatch">
        <ee:transform doc:name="Create headers">
            <ee:message >
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables >
                <ee:set-variable variableName="headers" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
var cols = ["col1","col2","col3"]
---
(cols joinBy ",") ++ "\n"
                ]]></ee:set-variable>
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
        <file:write doc:name="Create file with headers" path="out.csv">
            <file:content ><![CDATA[#[vars.headers]]]></file:content>
        </file:write>
        <batch:job jobName="fileAppenderJob">
            <batch:process-records >
                <batch:step name="Batch_Step" >
                    <batch:aggregator doc:name="Batch Aggregator" size="1000">
                        <ee:transform doc:name="Create CSV part">
                            <ee:message >
                                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/csv header=false
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
                            </ee:message>
                        </ee:transform>
                        <file:write doc:name="Append CSV" path="out.csv" mode="APPEND"/>
                    </batch:aggregator>
                </batch:step>
            </batch:process-records>
        </batch:job>
    </flow>
```

CSV Format ref: https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dataweave-formats-csv#writer_properties